# How to show text when date is ended in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a question
i'm trying to show a text when Some DATE is over.
i used this code to show the remaining date:

```
    =DATEDIF($J$1,B6,"Y") & " years, "&DATEDIF($J$1,B6,"YM") & " months, "&DATEDIF($J$1,B6,"MD")& " days "
```

and it works fine
now i need to show the text when ended
i tried this code but its not working

```
    =if(DATEDIF($J$1,B6,"Y") & " years, "&DATEDIF($J$1,B6,"YM") & " months, "&DATEDIF($J$1,B6,"MD")& " days ","Date Ended",DATEDIF($J$1,B6,"Y") & " years, "&DATEDIF($J$1,B6,"YM") & " months, "&DATEDIF($J$1,B6,"MD")& " days ")
```

Does any one have another way???

thanks in advance

Comment: give a proper example. When do you want your condition to be true/false? when to show the **Date Ended**? on what condition?

Comment: when the date ends i need to show DATE ENDED so its supposed to be on the FALSE area ...   if(a>=b, "true(DATE ENDED)",show the remaining date)

$j$1 = the current date   B6 = the date it supposed to end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work for you. I've added in an IF statement to check if the date is greater larger. If it is then it shows "TRUE" and displays the date, if not then it shows your previous value:

```
=IF($J$1-B6>0,"True ("&TEXT(B6,"dd mmmm yyyy")&")",DATEDIF($J$1,B6,"Y") & " years, "&DATEDIF($J$1,B6,"YM") & " months, "&DATEDIF($J$1,B6,"MD")& " days ")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably some language problem in the mix, but maybe

=IF($J$1-B6>0,"Date ended",DATEDIF($J$1,B6,"Y") & " years, "&DATEDIF($J$1,B6,"YM") & " months, "&DATEDIF($J$1,B6,"MD")& " days ")

... which means, if the date difference is 0 then show the text "Date ended", else show the calculated difference.